# How to prove this using modular arithmetics?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, totient-function

We know that p, q - odd primes such that $$(q - 1) | (p - 1)$$ and a is an integer such that $$ (a, pq) = 1 $$ How do we prove that $$ a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod pq $$

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem here though, as I don't have known values in order to compute all the potential solutions. Can you explain further?

Comment: From the answer you have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$. But the CRT says that if you have the system $x = 1 \pmod{p}$ and $x = 1 \pmod{q}$ with $p,q$ coprime (which they are as they are both prime), then there is a unique solution $\pmod {pq}$ satisfying both equations. We have a solution $x=a^{p-1}$ and a trivial solution $x=1$. But these must be unique $\pmod{pq}$. So $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is perfect. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad that helped :)